# Qualitatively and quantitatively finding the transient response of a current mirror

Tags: current-mirror

[image]

In a current mirror circuit, when Iss is doubled or multiplied by a factor, it takes some time to clone those values and reach the steady state.

I varied the width of the transistor and found that the delay to reach steady state increases. That could be due to the increase in parasitic capacitance. I am adding the circuit. Every capacitor shown in the circuit is a representation of internal capacitance (not externally added capacitors.)

What I though was that even though capacitance increases, the current flowing increases which means the maximum rate at which voltage across capacitor changes (I/C) does not increase that much.

Until I can quantify the increase of capacitance and current, I can't predict it properly.

From the simulation I know that the time taken to settle increases with an increase in width.

Can someone provide me an intuitive and mathematical explanation?

[image]

Comment: Simulation will be your best friend here.

Comment: hey @Andyaka I did simulation , the time increases with increase in width. But how to mathematical prove it will increase?

Comment: What do you mean by capacitor width? Your schematic is ambiguous in that you haven't put dots at nodes - maybe use the schematic from your simulator.

Comment: Oops sorry , I meant to say width of the MOSFETs (both). And is the circuit clear now? Its just a normal current mirror and I just showed the internal capacitors.

Comment: You assumed that current flowing will increase when capacitance (which capacitance) increase. But the current is supplied by a current source (?) So the current is probably fixed and so larger capacitance takes longer to charge.

Comment: Yeah that was so foolish of me. Like the voltage decreases but it's not directly proportional. And capacitance more or less doubles so definitely time increases. I need to just calculate it now. Thanks @AJN and

Answer (score 0):

Since the I remains same for all the cases with width varied , Vgs for each case varies by a small factor since its square of (Vgs-Vth). And capacitance increases by a larger factor.

Since maximum rate of change of voltage is (I/C), this value reduces by a larger factor than change in Vgs. Thus it takes more time to reach steady state.

PS: this is what I understood. If its wrong please correct me !